# Supervised learning for Text Data

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

I have a bunch of data with very different but certain causality. Like `Label1` -> `Value1` where `Label1` has the same dog name in text as `Value1`, but for example `Value2` has a same number in text as `Label2`, and I would like to search for the most common causality between this data and be able to predict `ValueX` if I insert `LabelX`... And I would like to ask for the recommendation which type of model should I use, Should be enough to use machine learning or should I go deeper to NN? (Btw. I think there is not a linear causallity). Sorry for question like this, but I can't find good hint on web, and I used to use only CNN till today, so I'm not very good with text analysis... :-(

Comment: Could you please explain your above problem with an example. In terms of how the data is, what would be your query to the model and the expected outcome.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer, I have in `txt` files. I would like to expect something like ts `.model` as outcome, Something what is usable more times. Data are like `Apple` - `Apple is nice`, `Cat` - `Cat0134`, `Doors` - `brown` (You can see, there is a relation between - but it's not obvious sometime)/ But I have about 50GB of data like this, so there could be some good output. I expect When I write `dog` it will output for dog is most common this pattern `dog_bark` or so...

Comment: In your case is 'dog' a class (tag) or dog is the input to the model and 'dog_bark' is the output?

Comment: It could be a class or a part of class, but it's not 100% certain.. Because there is a lot of words, Im not able to track it all..Its just like python's dict or I could compare it to credential infos, where is a name and pass and when I insert name like this I expect pass based on information from model... This could be pretty accurate case